# New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential throwing Authorization_RequestDenied

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-2.0

Trying to create a new client secret using powershell script. while executing **New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential** from powershell ISE, getting below error:

*New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential : Error occurred while executing SetApplication
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: 1234567-abcd-1234-7890-1234567890
DateTimeStamp: Mon, 12 Dec 2022 05:21:54 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed*

Attached image has the API permissions given for the SP used to authenticate to AD. The SP has read/write access on AD graph and MS Graph and has Admin consent on org as well.

[image]

Comment: Admin consent on the org level has already given to the SP but still it is not working..

Comment: See if following helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*Initially I tried the same command and got same error.*

**Console**:

[image]

Make sure the User or service principal with whom you are trying to login into azure has at least contributor role or owner role at subscription level.

*Go to portal -> Subscription -> Access control(IAM) -> Add role assignments ->Add  **`Contributor or Owner`** to your user or SP.*

[image]

Also, make sure User or SP has Azure AD role of at least **`Application Administrator`**.

*Go to portal -> Azure-Active-Directory -> Roles and Administrators ->Application Administrator -> Add the role to your User or SP.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

After Assigning both roles in my environment, I got the **`Client-Secret`** successfully.

**Console:**

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thanks for your inputs. Appreciate your time..